# How to get Error message when using pattern in angular 2

Tags: validation, angular

I have tried this code but it is not working.

```
<div>
    <span *ngIf="!usernameRef.errors?.required">Amount</span>
    <span *ngIf="!usernameRef.errors?.required">Cover amount required.</span>
    <span *ngIf="usernameRef.errors?.pattern">Cover amount invalid.</span>

     <input type="number" name="Amount" class="form-control" data-field="validate" placeholder="50 000" [(ngModel)]="Amount" 
    required #usernameRef="ngModel" pattern="[0-9]*" /> 
    </div>
```

Comment: have you fields are wrapped inside `form`?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is also valid from two reasons:

1. Your input type is a number. You can't type letters.
2. [0-9]* - the asterisk means - 0 or more occurrences.

Comment: 1. Input type is number. It will not take any special character only taking + and - . I want to restrict + and - also.